# event.stopPropagation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a video preview system.
my source code snippet is

```
<li id="liVideoList">
    <div class="thumbitem">
        <div>
            <a>
                <img alt="" src="images/download.png" onclick="download('ID')" title="Download" />                                     
            </a>
        </div>
        <img class="imagThumb" alt="Thumbs" class="thumb" src="#Path#" />
    </div>                                           
</li>
```

There is a function to preview the video on clicking the li.It is dynamically doing and no issue with that.But if i clik on the download button which is inside the li, both the functions of li and download button is working, which means the preview is changing undesirably.
to avoid this I added the below function after the code of dowload

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

and the code looks like

```
function Download(Id) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyWebMethods.asmx/Download",
        data: { "Id": Id}
    }).complete(function (data) {

    });
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

but still both the functions are working

Comment: where are you getting `event` from?  you need to pass it through to the function as a variable

Comment: How is that image going to be clicked, when it's parent isn't displayed?

Comment: it is doing dynamically

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function DownloadAsset(AssetId, e) {

    if (!e) var e = window.event
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    // your ajax call
    $.ajax({....})
}
```

Where `e` refers to the event in all browsers and you can access the event.

Comment: Is that should comes before ajax call.

Comment: he can also pass the event in the call, ` onclick="downloadAsset('#UUID#', event)"`

Comment: Yes, it will be called before ajax call and it will not prevent the ajax call from executing from anyways...

Answer (score 4):

Firstly your HTML is invalid, as your `a` element has no `name` or `href` attribute. Secondly, if you're using jQuery for logic, you may as well use it to hook up your events:

```
<li runat="server" id="liAssetList">
    <div class="asset_thumbitem">
        <div class="thumboptions" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#"><img alt="Download" src="images/download_icon.png" data-asset="#UUID#" title="Download" /></a>
        </div>
        <img class="assetlist_imagThumb" alt="Thumbs" class="asset_thumb" src="#ThumbnailPath#" />
    </div>                                           
</li>
```

```js
$('.thumboptions a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var assetId = $('img', this).data('asset');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ClientMethods.asmx/DownloadAssets",
        data: { "AssetId": assetId}
    }).complete(function (data) {
        // do something..
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding the e.preventDefault(); Fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change this:

```
DownloadAsset(AssetId)
```

to this:

```
DownloadAsset(AssetId, event)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to `return false` from the `DownloadAsset` function

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.