# Event listener and button click conflict

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I have a menu that needs to obey the following behavior:

- Open with an external button press
- Close when there is a click outside it's boundaries

The problem is, that the button to open is also outside the boundaries of the menu and so currently, the button press is opening the editor menu, and then the click listener is immediately closing it again. I've tried using variables and element data so that the click listener only activates if the menu is already open, but the event listener is slower than the button click and so the menu has already been expanded (as far as the listener knows) by the time it is activated. I know I can solve this using timeout so the data isn't changed to "expanded = true" until after the click listener has activated, but this seems kind of clunky and I'm wondering if there is a better option.
[Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/klaytonme/75kbsc2d/5/)

And the js code that accompanies it:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!document.getElementById("menu").contains(event.target) && document.getElementById("menu").dataset.open) {
    closeMenu();
  }
});

//Expand menu
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").dataset.open = true;
  document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "80vh";
  console.log("open");
}
//Collapse menu
function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").dataset.open = false;
  document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "0";
  console.log("close");
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! Here's my solution based on @Addison Schmidt's answer that fixes a couple of errors:

```
function openMenu(e) {
  if (!event) var e = window.event
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

  document.getElementById("menu").dataset.open = true;
  document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "80vh";
  console.log("open");
}
```

Source: [Event.stopPropagation Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927538/event-stoppropagation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the button prevent its parent element from registering the click by taking the event parameter in openMenu, and calling the `stopPropogation` method on it.

```
function openMenu(e) {
  e.stopPropogation()
  document.getElementById("menu").dataset.open = true;
  document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "80vh";
  console.log("open");
}
```

[How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)